# Begin a rolling sum based on an observation in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following:

```
data = [100,100,100,100,10,100,10,100]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':data, 'b':data})
df

    a   b
0   100 100
1   100 100
2   100 100
3   100 100
4   10  10
5   100 100
6   10  10
7   100 100

df['cond_a'] = (df.a == 100).rolling(3).sum() == 3
df

    a   b   cond_a
0   100 100 False
1   100 100 False
2   100 100 True
3   100 100 True
4   10  10  False
5   100 100 False
6   10  10  False
7   100 100 False
```

What i would like to do now is add another column (df['cond_b_count'])  which counts the occurrences of 100 values AFTER the observation of 'cond_a == true' on a rolling window of 3.  so what i would end up with would be something like:

```
    a   b   cond_a  cond_b_count
0   100 100 False   NaN
1   100 100 False   NaN
2   100 100 True    NaN
3   100 100 True    1.0
4   10  10  False   1.0
5   100 100 False   2.0
6   10  10  False   1.0
7   100 100 False   2.0
```

something like this, which is ofcourse incorrect, as it doesnt take into check first for cond_a being true before applying the rolling(3) sum.

```
df['cond-b'] = (df.b == 100).rolling(3).sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible in one-line. Here's what I'd do:

- find the first `True` value in `cond_a`, let's call it `offset`;
- mask `df['b']` with `nan` up to this `offset`;
- find the sums in rolling windows on the masked column;
- replace zeros with `nan` up to the `offset` in the result from the previous step.

The code below is mirroring the list above.

```
offset = df[df['cond_a']].index[0]
s = df['b'].where(df.index > offset, pd.NA)
s = (s == 100).rolling(3).sum()
df['cond_b'] = s.where(df.index > offset, pd.NA)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Comment: @ljmc Thanks for your feedback. Please tell me what exactly you, as a student, would like to know about this case? I would appreciate it if you avoid an abstract answer about the usefulness of additional explanations in general and help me understand what details of my answer are not clear to you.

Comment: as I said in the above *generic* comment, you should add why and how this code works, especially line 2 which has many different operations condensed in a single line.

Comment: @ljmc I'd like to get your feedback once again if the code is clear enough this time from your POV. What else would you like to clarify along with the line 2?

Comment: Looks much better and can be left as is. If you still want to improve it, you can add an example input/output to turn your answer in an MRE, and links to the pandas documentation for the functions/methods you used.

Comment: @ljmc Okay, thanks. I'll stick with this one. One last question. Could you tell me if you were really interested in the answer, or was it just a routine decision provoked by a queue of low quality answers?

Comment: It was just in the queue, otherwise I wouldn’t have started the comment by saying it was reviewed in the low quality queue.

Comment: @Vitalizzare thx. ur asnwer is correct, but my example was incorrect.  in fact i want both conditions to be rolling. so b can only be true within a window of 3 from the last observation of a=true.  Therefore were i to correct my example - row 6 and 7 would be 0 (or nan).
regardless i will mark your answer as correct as it did answer the question as presented.

Comment: FYI: something like this is what i was looking for i think:
```((df['cond_a'].rolling(3).sum().shift(1)>=1) & (df['b'] == 100))```